# Why C++ pretends to forget previously parsed templates?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, c++20

Here is data serialization program which compiles with `gcc 11.1`:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <ranges>
#include <concepts>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

void write( fstream & f, const integral auto & data ) {
    f.write( (const char*)&data, sizeof( data ) );
}

void write( fstream & f, const pair<auto,auto> & p ) {
    write( f, p.first );
    write( f, p.second );
}

template< ranges::range T >
void write( fstream & f, const T & data ) {
    const uint64_t size = ranges::size( data );
    write( f, size );
    for ( const auto & i : data )
        write( f, i );
}

int main() {
    auto f = fstream( "spagetti", ios::out | ios::binary );
    const bool pls_compile = true;
    if constexpr (pls_compile) {
        write( f, pair< int, int >( 123, 777 ) );
        write( f, map< int, int >{ { 1, 99 }, { 2, 98 } } );
    }
    else
        write( f, pair< map< int, int >, int >( { { 1, 99 }, { 2, 98 } }, 777 ) );
}
```

which made me a happy developer of serialization *library* which provides functions to serialize to file anything that is `integral || pair || range`. But it turned out that if you set `pls_compile = false`, then compilation fails with `spagetti.cpp:12:10: error: no matching function for call to 'write(std::fstream&, const std::map<int, int>&)'`. It can't be fixed by moving declaration of `write( pair )` past `write( range )` because `pls_compile = true` will stop compiling then.

What is the best way to fix it and why compiler *forgets* about existence of `write( range )` while generating implementation of `write( pair< map, int > )` based on `write( pair )` template? It clearly should be already familiar with `write( range )` since it already proceeded down to `write( pair< map, int > )`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order for a function to participate in overload resolution, it must be *declared* before the point of the *use* in the compilation unit.  If it is not declared until after the point of use, it will not be a possible overload, even if the compile has proceeded past the point of definition (eg, if the use is in a instatiation of a template defined before the declation but triggered by a use of a template afterwards, as you have here.)

The easiest fix is to just forward declare your templates/functions.  You can't go wrong forward declaring *everything* at the top of the file:

```
void write( fstream & f, const integral auto & data );
void write( fstream & f, const pair<auto,auto> & p );
template< ranges::range T >
void write( fstream & f, const T & data );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a way to somehow force compiler to respect *all* the declarations including future ones? It's hard to reason about order especially when it's usage-defined and differs from other languages.

Comment: And it's weird how C++ introduces something like second layer of templates declaration order. Can't yet see a reason why compiler would explicitly ignore something that was already  parsed. Is there any reason for such behavior? Is it somewhere explicitly defined as a language feature?

Comment: @Slaus It is intentionally designed so that unqualified name lookup in template instantiations considers only names already declared before the template definition (rather than the point of instantiation) to avoid ODR violations. If you included a template in a header file in multiple translation units with only some of them declaring the extra overloads afterwards, then the translation units may both instantiate the template with overload resolution giving different results. That would cause undefined behavior.

Comment: @Slaus But ADL is performed from the point-of-instantiation for templates, so you can put the extra declarations of `write` in the namespace of the types they operate on. That's the usual approach. Unfortunately you can't do that for standard library types or built-in types.

Comment: To make it work for “future declarations”, You need to use customisation points.   plain ADL won’t work as you are not allowed to inject into std namespace. You could use tag_invoke , which you can inject into the library namespace. Or  you could use class template specialisation. Or you could wait until at least c++26 where we have language support for customisation point. Edit: at op @Slaus

Comment: @user17732522 I guess *"C++ is designed that way"*, but I think it's just a misconception because I can't see a specific rule/statement in C++ that explicitly states such *"hidden definitions spagetti*" where anything is dependent on an order. When anything is dependent on an order is more of imperative style than declarative, but templates is clearly declarative part of the language. Currently, C++ resulting program is dependent on `#include`s order and it's OK. Such template overload matching dependent on hidden detangling process introduces more *undefined behavior* than solves, I think ;(

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer stated, you could declare all your functions first before define any of them. However, this answer is about OP's another question

> Is there a way to somehow force compiler to respect all the declarations including future ones?

Normally, you could use some Customisation Point technique to achieve your goal, such as C++20 CPO (niebloids), and plain old ADL.

But in your particular example, all types are the STL library types and inside `namespace std`. Thus you cannot define your functions inside the `std` to make them part of ADL. Thus C++20 CPO and plain ADL won't work.

There are several approaches which can make your example work.

## `tag_invoke`

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <ranges>
#include <concepts>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

namespace lib{
    inline constexpr struct write_fn{
        // skip noexcept and requires for simplicity
        decltype(auto) operator()(std::fstream& f, const auto& t) const {
            return tag_invoke(*this, f, t);
        }
    } write{};

    void tag_invoke(write_fn, std::fstream & f, const integral auto & data){
        f.write( (const char*)&data, sizeof( data ) );
    }

    void tag_invoke(write_fn, std::fstream & f, const pair<auto,auto> & p ) {
        lib::write( f, p.first );
        lib::write( f, p.second );
    }

    void tag_invoke(write_fn, std::fstream & f, const std::ranges::range auto& data) {
        const uint64_t size = std::ranges::size( data );
        lib::write(f, size );
        for (const auto& i : data){
            lib::write( f, i );
        }
    }

}

int main() {
    auto f = std::fstream( "spagetti", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary );
    
    lib::write(f, std::pair< int, int >( 123, 777 ) );
    lib::write(f, std::map< int, int >{ { 1, 99 }, { 2, 98 } } );
    lib::write(f, std::pair<std::map< int, int >, int >( { { 1, 99 }, { 2, 98 } }, 777 ) );
}
```

[godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/s6648j3qa)

This works also because of ADL. as the tag `write_fn` is inside `lib` namespace

## Class Template Specialisation

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <ranges>
#include <concepts>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

namespace lib{

    template <class T>
    struct write_impl;

    inline constexpr struct write_fn{
        // skip noexcept and requires for simplicity
        decltype(auto) operator()(std::fstream& f, const auto& t) const {
            return write_impl<std::decay_t<decltype(t)>>::apply(f,t);
        }
    } write{};

    template <integral T>
    struct write_impl<T>{
        static void apply(std::fstream & f, const T& data){
            f.write( (const char*)&data, sizeof( data ) );
        }
    };

    template <class T, class U>
    struct write_impl<std::pair<T, U>>{
        static void apply(std::fstream & f, const std::pair<T, U>& p){
            lib::write( f, p.first );
            lib::write( f, p.second );
        }
    };

    template <std::ranges::range T>
    struct write_impl<T>{
        static void apply(std::fstream & f, const T& data) {
            const uint64_t size = std::ranges::size( data );
            lib::write(f, size );
            for (const auto& i : data){
                lib::write( f, i );
            }
        }
    };

}

int main() {
    auto f = std::fstream( "spagetti", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary );
    
    lib::write(f, std::pair< int, int >( 123, 777 ) );
    lib::write(f, std::map< int, int >{ { 1, 99 }, { 2, 98 } } );
    lib::write(f, std::pair<std::map< int, int >, int >( { { 1, 99 }, { 2, 98 } }, 777 ) );
}
```

[godbolt link] (https://godbolt.org/z/n7Gbosscn)

## Language support

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2547r0.pdf

However, I don't think the authors have implemented a compiler that supports it

Comment: side note, in general you cannot take ranges by `const &` as some range's begin is not const. I haven't fixed that for you